# Using yarn in firebase-generated yaml file causes build fail in guthub action

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions, firebase-hosting, yarn-lock.json, yarnpkg-v3

My build step fails when running the following github action. Note that I'm using yarn v1.22.19.

yml (abbreviated):

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: staging
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: yarn install && yarn run build
```

When the above action runs, I get the below error (abbreviated).

```
Run yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ tsc && vite build
Version 5.3.3
tsc: The TypeScript Compiler - Version 5.3.3

COMMON COMMANDS

//shortened
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

How do I avoid the above error? I've recently switched from npm to yarn and from CRA to Vite, if it matters.

.yarnrc.yml:

```
compressionLevel: mixed
enableGlobalCache: true
nodeLinker: node-modules
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.19.cjs
```

package.json: (has some unnecessary scripts left from testing)

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.10.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.0.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preci": "rm -rf node_modules",
    "ci": "yarn install --frozen-lockfile",
    "setfbproj": "firebase use --clear --project='myproject'"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@redux-devtools/core": "^3.13.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.45",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.15.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.15.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "vite": "^5.0.10",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.19"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User error, I had missed to commit tsconfig, which caused my WIP project to fail to build.